# Applied JS to Drupal theme doesn't work correctly, but it works fine outside Drupal

Tags: 7, theming, javascript

Applied this JS http://jsfiddle.net/tbq8eo8b/10/ to webforms. As you can see in fiddle, it calculates total amount. When in Drupal, it gives `0` no matter what amounts you select, it always prints `0`. What's wrong?

Drupal code:

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.bartik = {
attach: function(context, settings) {

/*Add your js code here*/
    var $selects = $("select").change(function (e) {
        var total = 0;
        $selects.each(function() {
            var val = this.value.match(/\$(\d+)/);
            total += val ? +val[1] : 0;
        });
        $(".total").val(total);
    });

}

};
}(jQuery));
```

Also console prints:

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
$("select").change(function ()
```

Comment: First thing, it should be `$("select", context)` as your top-level selector. Second thing, are you sure it is run after form is ready and prepared? Third thing: How you debugged it? Does it find selects at all? Are select's values in the format you expect them to be? and so on...

Comment: Try changing `Drupal.behaviors.bartik` with `Drupal.behaviors.something_unique`. You sure there is an input field with `total` class? Also, you will need to use more precise selectors.

Comment: I changed it, but same. Under input.total it still prints 0.

Comment: What about questions from my comment? Have you tested these things?

Comment: I applied the context part. Still same. It prints 0 in the input that has class .total Also updated question with Console errors. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Try removing `$` before select variable in `var $select` and `$selects.each(function() {` as there is no need to add `$` before variables in javascript, also as you are using `$` for jQuery so may be adding before variable is causing problem.

Comment: I updated the thread. The errors are gone now. Thanks for helping though.

Comment: Please don't hide the information that was needed to answer this question. Answer works, to some extent at least, so give future users a chance to benefit from it, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
}(jQuery));
```

should be

```
})(jQuery);
```

in your last line of code.

Comment: Yes, I already fixed that, didn't change anything though.

Comment: @OptimusPrime At least it will remove the console error *$ is not a function* and your script will be executed at all. Please don't [chameleon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/225745) your question now.

Comment: No, error is still there and same.

Comment: @OptimusPrime are you sure your browser refreshed js files?

Comment: I'm sorry. You were right, the errors are gone, But it still prints zeros, but in the jsfiddle the script works fine. What is Drupal preventing from working it right? Why it still prints zeros instead of total amount? Thanks for helping.

Comment: @OptimusPrime I think now it's time for you to ask a follow-up question. Your script changed, it started to run, so it is significantly improved :) Try to find an answer to **"Does it find selects at all? Are select's values in the format you expect them to be?"** and ask new question - then we will be able to help you further.

Comment: It will be basically a duplicate question then. If it wouldn't find selects it wouldn't be printing anything in .total field. Now it prints zeros, so it finds it. And the same exact script in fiddle link does work correctly. What I did in Drupal was just wrap it up.

Comment: @OptimusPrime nope, you are wrong. `var total = 0;` does not require any selects to be executed, and `.each` over no elements will leave that `0` in place. So we still don't know if any selects are found in `$selects.each(` line. I know that "common logic" suggest that if `.change` works, there need to be some selects in `$selects`. But I'm not sure if there really are any.

Comment: I'm lost now. So what should I ask in next question? What would be the correct question title?