# Internal/External JS don't work with Drupal, but works fine in static HTML/JSFiddle

Tags: 7, theming, javascript

Continued from here [Applied JS to Drupal theme doesn't work correctly, but it works fine outside Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/130708/applied-js-to-drupal-theme-doesnt-work-correctly-but-it-works-fine-outside-dru)

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tbq8eo8b/10/ (it calculates total, in Drupal it calculates zeros - why?)

Raw:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $selects = $("select").change(function (e) {
        var total = 0;
        $selects.each(function() {
            var val = this.value.match(/\$(\d+)/);
            total += val ? +val[1] : 0;
        });
        $(".total").val(total);
    });
});
```

Drupal:

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.totalAmount = {
attach: function(context, settings) {

/*Add your js code here */
    var $selects = $("select").change(function (e) {
        var total = 0;
        $selects.each(function() {
            var val = this.value.match(/\$(\d+)/);
            total += val ? +val[1] : 0;
        });
        $(".total").val(total);
    });
}
};
})(jQuery);
```

2nd attempt with internal Drupal:

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var $selects = $("select").change(function (e) {
        var total = 0;
        $selects.each(function() {
            var val = this.value.match(/^\$(\d+)$/);
            total += val ? +val[1] : 0;
        });
        $(".total").val(total);
    });
});
  </script>
```

As you see the code is identical (except Drupal wrappings), so why it's not working on Drupal? Why it prints zeros in .total field, but in JSFiddle it works fine?

Comment: Add `console.log(this.value);` just before or after `var val = this.value.match(/^\$(\d+)$/);` and tell us what's there. Similarly, `console.log($selects.count);` before ` $selects.each(function() {`, please :)

Comment: It just prints single numbers per line like 1, 2, or '(an empty string)'. And the $selects.count line gives 'undefined'.

Comment: Try removing $ sign before selects variable as it is not needed in js and may be confusing there.

Comment: It still prints zeros. And no errors. So it's same with or without $.

Comment: OK, and what's in `console.log( val ? +val[1] : 0 );`? I have my suspicion now, but I need to know this one thing, to confirm or discard it before I'll post answerer.

Comment: 4 zeros '0' per line for every select list action. Unless I included in wrong place that console.log line.

Comment: @OptimusPrime OK, my suspicion was wrong. I know, not helpful for you. Sorry.

Comment: @OptimusPrime: How are the select field's options set up? In your fiddle example, the select options have no "internal" value but in webforms options must be set as key|value and `this.value` would than return the key. - EDIT: To clarify, in the fiddle it reads `<option>$200</option>` but webform would produce something like `<option value="article1">$200</option>`.

Comment: Have you tried assigning the `select` lists to a variable first, before you actually use it in a `.change()` statement? That `$selects gives undefined` line is a pretty big clue to me that the variable is not initialized yet. Or you may want to be a bit more explicit about the selectors, like `$('#content select')` or something like that. My advice is start very simple! Then work your way up. Debug your steps.

Comment: Can you share code examples of how you think it should look via jsfiddle? Honestly I don't get it what's wrong with Drupal running this script, it works fine outside it.

Comment: Did you see my updated answer? It works in my test environment now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've rebuilt the scenario and my guess now is that you don't want the value of the select field but the option text for your parsing purpose. Thus, the script should probably be something like this:

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.totalAmount = {
attach: function(context, settings) {

    /*Add your js code here */
    var selects = $("select").change(function (e) {
        var total = 0;
        selects.each(function() {
          var val = $("#"+this.id+"  option[value='"+this.value+"']").text().match(/\$(\d+)/);
          total += val ? +val[1] : 0;
        });
        $(".total").val(total);
    });
}
};
})(jQuery);
```

This is how it looks like working:

[image]

This is how the first select's options are setup as a webform component

[image]

To retrieve prices, one would need to change the regex line to

```
var val = $("#"+this.id+" option[value='"+this.value+"']").text().match(/\$(\d+(\.\d{2})?)/);
```

Working example:

[image]

To have the total always be display with trailing zeros, replace the last script line with

```
$(".total").val(total.toFixed(2));
```

To make the script also work with thousands separator, change the script into

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.totalAmount = {
attach: function(context, settings) {

/*Add your js code here */
    var selects = $("select").change(function (e) {
        var total = 0;
        selects.each(function() {
                var val = $("#"+this.id+" option[value='"+this.value+"']").text().match(/\$(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?)/);
                        total += val ? +parseFloat(val[1].replace(/,/g,'')) : 0;
        });
        $(".total").val('$'+total.toFixed(2));
    });
}
};
})(jQuery);
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks for helping. I'm about to test it out. I avoid the values, because the end-user would be creating those forms from time to time with various settings and fields and who knows what values they will use and etc.

Comment: Woah, looks like it works great. I still don't get it what you did. Also any ideas when selecting $42.30 it gives in total amount only 42, why it strips 30 cents?

Comment: First, the key line is `var val = $("#"+this.id+"  option[value='"+this.value+"']").text().match(/\$(\d+)/);` where I get the option element (child of select) which has the selected value, retrieve the text content and then do the regex. The regex currently only looks for integers as `\d+`stands for any number of following digits (no period). You would need to change that to `\d+(\.d{2})?` for price tags.

Comment: I still get the same. Does it work for you if you replace it?

Comment: See updated answer for the replacement line and a screenshot. I forgot a backslash in my last comment (sorry).

Comment: Thanks very much, it works now, but there's another issue. It doesn't pickup in thousands because they have commas e.g. $1,123.50 But it all works up to $999.99

Comment: Thousands separator in javascript is not as straight forward as decimal point, but it's possible. Drawback: you need to replace the commas which turns the value into a string, so we would need parseFloat to turn it back in to a number. See updated answer.

Comment: All works great. Cheers.